# forcing winbind/samba to use single server

Tags: samba, winbind

In a network, there are 2 AD servers. We are integrating samba and squid with AD for user authentication. Interestingly one of the servers does not allow us for enough security level. So we have to use one of them. In spite of using IP and realm of the working server, winbind/samba may choose to use other. We can examine this situation with "net ads info".

Is there any way to ping samba to use single server as AD and password server and not to allow chosing others in the AD pool?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this directive in `smb.conf` in `[Global]` section :

```
password server = SERVER_AD.domain.tld
```

This will force Samba to use a specific Server to validate username/password authentication.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#PASSWORDSERVER

Comment: This setting is already added but does not work.

Comment: What makes you think that it does not work ?

Comment: Using `wbinfo --getdcname=DOMAIN` indicates that the setting is not obeyed.